# Proxy from Domino 8.5.3 to Connections

Tags: proxy, xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to setup a proxy configuration on a dev 853 domino server, so I can connect to a dev connections server from an XPage (using java).

It's an SSO environment, and both the domino server and connections server are protected by WebSEAL.  I want to make server-side calls in java (using the Apache HTTP Client), so my XPages application can make a call across to the Connections server.

I followed some information I found in Niklas Heidloff's Social Enabler documentation: http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/DA2F4D351A9F15B28625792D002D1F18/%24file/SocialEnabler111006.pdf
and also in here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/inotes-full/index.html

I setup the proxy like this:

```
Context:    /xsp/proxy/BasicProxy/
URL:        https://connectionsserver.acompany.com
Actions:    GET,HEAD,POST,DELETE,PUT
Cookies:    -List of cookies-
Mime-types: *
Headers:    User-Agent,Accept*,Content*,Authorization*,Set-Cookie
```

When I try the call, it gives me the following error:

```
2/28/13 12:34 PM: Exception Thrown
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: No trusted certificate found
at com.ibm.domino.servlets.proxy.BasicProxy.throwServletException(BasicProxy.java:765)
at com.ibm.domino.servlets.proxy.BasicProxy.service(BasicProxy.java:357)..
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: No trusted certificate found
```

I thought that passing the cookies across in this way should work (the cookies should work between both the domino-webseal and connections-webseal environments).

The error suggests that I need to import a certificate.  I don't have access to the domino server to allow me to import certificates, so before I request that, I wanted to check I wasn't missing something from somewhere else.

Is there something else I am missing?  Or any suggestions on doing this a different way?

Thanks, 
Pam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the certificates if they are not present. That is what the error message is indicating. There is [IBM Technote 21588966](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588966) describing the necessary steps.

Furthermore (that could become the next showstopper after you sorted out SSL) you have to have a hard look how WebSeal is configured. The challenge here: WebSeal is designed to accommodate any possible backends and it is easy to get it almost working - almost as in: works for direct access via browser but fails on server-2-server or Ajax etc. The super-highly-recommended-ignore-on-your-own-risk setting for Connections/Domino is to use WebSeal's LTPA capabilities and not some ludicrous code injection.

Hth